# Как выровнять блоки по высоте по отношению к другим

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять блоки по высоте, чтобы в случае добавления текста высота была у всех одинакова. 1 Изображение как в данный момент. 2 изображение как нужно сделать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте родителю `display: flex`, а кнопке (желательно, чтобы она была прямым дочерним ребёнком родителя) добавьте `margin-top: auto`.

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 80%;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #333;
}

.text span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #09f;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"><span></span></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"><span></span><span></span></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрАрхипов, если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правильный (галочка слева, под оценкой ответа)